# What does wave nature of particle mean?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, waves

What does wave nature of a particle actually mean. Does it mean that a particle exhibits wave-like motion while moving forward in space? Or does it mean that an electron acts as an emitting source of waves.

Sorry if this makes no sense. I am utterly confused.

Comment: see https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/40985/179320, I think it might help you

Comment: my answer here might help also https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/609407/trust-in-wave-particle-duality/609509#609509